# How to change height on Facebook like box widget (iframe)?

Tags: css, facebook, plugins

I am trying to change the height of the facebook like box widget on the sidebar of my site, however I can't seem to figure out what css to target in order to do this. I'd like to change it about 200. Here is the current code being used. Any ideas?

```
</div><div id="facebook-likebox-3" class="widget widget_facebook_likebox"><h4 class="Facebook Like Box widget-title"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/noahsdadcom">Like Us On Facebook</a></h4><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnoahsdadcom&#038;width=300&#038;height=432&#038;colorscheme=light&#038;show_faces=true&#038;stream=false&#038;header=false&#038;force_wall=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 432px; background: #fff"></iframe></div><div id="text-43" class="widget widget_text">            <div class="textwidget"><div id="cse-search-form" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
```

Comment: You cannot edit an iframe's css unless you're the one who controls it. Since Facebook controls this iframe, there's no way you can edit it's CSS.

Comment: @AdityaSaxena Actually there is a way to do it. Check out the answer below. It worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `height` on the `<iframe>` using `!important`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/TpZ9k/

```css
#facebook-likebox-3 iframe {
    height: 200px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA !important;
}​
```